# Invalid property 'tempsReglementaireBusiness' of bean class

Tags: java, spring

I have an Invalid property 'tempsReglementaireBusiness' of bean class in my web application

My class:

```
public class ExportDepassement12HeuresCSV {

    @Autowired
    private TempsReglementaireBusiness tempsReglementaireBusiness;

...
}
```

My application context service:

```
    <bean id="exportDepassement12heuresCSV"
        class="fr.edfgdf.tamaris.intervention.goulotte.export.ExportDepassement12HeuresCSV">
    <property name="tempsReglementaireBusiness" ref="tempsReglementaireBusiness"></property>
    </bean>

....
    <bean id="tempsReglementaireBusiness"
        class="fr.edfgdf.tamaris.intervention.goulotte.service.impl.TempsReglementaireBusinessImpl">
        <property name="ressourceManager" ref="ressourceManager" />
        <property name="affectationRessourceManager" ref="affectationRessourceManager" />
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager" />
        <property name="affectationActiviteManager" ref="affectationActiviteManager" />
        <property name="mainOeuvreManager" ref="mainOeuvreManager" />
        <property name="reportingReposService" ref="reportingReposService" />
        <property name="tourneeManager" ref="tourneeManager" />
        <property name="entiteManager" ref="entiteManager" />
        <property name="rvaEntiteRegionaleManager" ref="rvaEntiteRegionaleManager" />
        <property name="rvaEntiteRegionaleDtoTranslator" ref="rvaEntiteRegionaleDtoTranslator" />
        <property name="exportService" ref="exportService" />
        <property name="exportMessageSender" ref="exportMessageSender" />
        <property name="motifDepassementManager" ref="motifDepassementManager" />
        <property name="activiteLocaleManager" ref="activiteLocaleManager" />
        <property name="activiteNationaleManager" ref="activiteNationaleManager" />
        <property name="interventionManager" ref="interventionManager" />
        <property name="depassementTempsManager" ref="depassementTempsManager" />
    </bean>

...
```

All is declared but when i compil i have this error:

> Caused By: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException:
>   Invalid property 'tempsReglementaireBusiness' of bean class
>   [fr.edfgdf.tamaris.intervention.goulotte.export.ExportDepassement12HeuresCSV]:
>   Bean property 'tempsReglementaireBusiness' is not writable or has an
>   invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the
>   return type of the getter?    at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1064)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:924)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
>     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Thx.

Comment: The propery is private and the exception tells you `'tempsReglementaireBusiness' is not writable or has an invalid setter method` - what does the setter look like?

Comment: @Thomas i have use the Autowired

Comment: That's why I hate Spring.

Comment: @Mercer I don't know Autowired in detail but the message tells that Spring is looking for a setter, so either Autowired needs a setter or your config overrides the annotation and Autowired is not used.

Answer (score 1):

As you have autowired `TempsReglementaireBusiness` in your `ExportDepassement12HeuresCSV` class, you don't need to have a `property` entry defined for this while defining `ExportDepassement12HeuresCSV` in your config file. Change the bean definition of `ExportDepassement12HeuresCSV` to this:

```
<bean id="exportDepassement12heuresCSV"
      class="fr.edfgdf.tamaris.intervention.goulotte.export.ExportDepassement12HeuresCSV">

</bean>
```

Comment: not works my variable is not initilaisez, i have null pointer exception

Comment: Try adding `@Qualifier("tempsReglementaireBusiness")` along with `@Autowired` to `private TempsReglementaireBusiness tempsReglementaireBusiness;`.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the changes you made and the new stacktrace. Or you can try adding getters/setters for`tempsReglementaireBusiness` in your `ExportDepassement12HeuresCSV` class and removing `@Autowired` annotation. Here you need to define `tempsReglementaireBusiness` as property for `ExportDepassement12HeuresCSV` bean.